# How do I search and find a specific value in a hash in a list? Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, hash, updating

I am an amateur Python user, so bear with me. I created a list, and filled it with hashes. But I am having trouble, because I need to search the entire list to find the first hash with a specific value and update it. Does anyone know how?

```
character = [{"No": 1, "Name":"Jeff", "Level": 29, "Health": 290},
             {"No": 2, "Name":"Bill", "Level": 31, "Health": 310},
             {"No": 3, "Name":"EMPTY", "Level": 0, "Health": 0},
             {"No": 4, "Name":"EMPTY", "Level": 0, "Health": 0},
             {"No": 5, "Name":"EMPTY", "Level": 0, "Health": 0},
             {"No": 6, "Name":"EMPTY", "Level": 0, "Health": 0}]
```

In this code, I need to find the first instance of the empty name, and update its hash with another hash

I tried to use indexing, but it did not work, saying "Invalid Syntax"

```
x = character.index("EMPTY")
character[x].update(player)
print(character)
```

Comment: Could you please show me a demo? Like before and after of the update?

Comment: Sure
player =  [{"No": 1, "Name":"Player", "Level": 30, "Health": 300}]

then after:
character = [{"No": 1, "Name":"Jeff", "Level": 29, "Health": 290},
             {"No": 2, "Name":"Bill", "Level": 31, "Health": 310},
             {"No": 3, "Name":"Player", "Level": 30, "Health": 300},
             {"No": 4, "Name":"EMPTY", "Level": 0, "Health": 0},
             {"No": 5, "Name":"EMPTY", "Level": 0, "Health": 0},
             {"No": 6, "Name":"EMPTY", "Level": 0, "Health": 0}]

Comment: Hash? What hash are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

yea,list can't use index method directly。
should used linear search to catch 'Name' == 'Empty'。

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to only populate the `character` list with active players, rather than empty ones. That way you can append new players directly to the list when they're created.

Nevertheless, this should give you what you're after:

```
# create a new player. NOTE: "No" is updated when appending to character list
player = {"No": 1, "Name":"Player", "Level": 30, "Health": 300}

# find the character index
idx = 0
for c in character:
    if c['Name'] == 'EMPTY':
        break
    else:
        idx += 1

# update player number
player['No'] = idx + 1


# replace element in list
character[idx] = player
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can update the first occurrence:

```
character = [{"No": 1, "Name":"Jeff", "Level": 29, "Health": 290},
             {"No": 2, "Name":"Bill", "Level": 31, "Health": 310},
             {"No": 3, "Name":"EMPTY", "Level": 0, "Health": 0},
             {"No": 4, "Name":"EMPTY", "Level": 0, "Health": 0},
             {"No": 5, "Name":"EMPTY", "Level": 0, "Health": 0},
             {"No": 6, "Name":"EMPTY", "Level": 0, "Health": 0}]


player = {"No": 7, "Name":"Alex", "Level": 25, "Health": 250}

for character_hash in character:
    if character_hash["Name"] == "EMPTY":
        character_hash.update(player)
        break  # Break out of the loop after updating the first empty character

print(character)
```